# If Condition operator: unary operator expected when undecalared variable is provided

Tags: shell-script

I am running the below script which throws me an errors with unary operator issue. In the main shell script program, I will be using this existing_sum_check variable down the line but I want to perform this check anyhow. How can I avoid this error?

**Program:**

```
#!/bin/sh

latest_sum_check=10101;

if [ $latest_sum_check != $EXISTING_SUM_CHECK ]; then
    EXISTING_SUM_CHECK = $latest_sum_check;

    echo $EXISTING_SUM_CHECK;
    echo "Please process";
else
    echo "Do not process"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You have essentially `[ something != $bar ]`.

If `$bar` is empty, that turns into `if [ something != ]`, which of course doesn't work, since the equality test requires two operands. Though at least Bash's `test`/`[` has a funny way of stating that: apparently it checks the number of arguments, and since there's only two expects the first to be a unary operator. 
The `something` there isn't one, so it complains.

[So, put quotes around the variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373):

```
if [ "$latest_sum_check" != "$EXISTING_SUM_CHECK" ]; then ...
```

And this runs a command `EXISTING_SUM_CHECK` with the equals sign and whatever comes from the expansion of the variable as parameters:

```
 EXISTING_SUM_CHECK = $latest_sum_check;
```

Variable assignments in the shell don't take spaces around them.

Answer (score 1):

This is an error condition of your test due to having an undeclared variable $EXISTING_SUM_CHECK.  You should have another check such as:

```
if [ -z $EXISTING_SUM_CHECK ]; then
    EXISTING_SUM_CHECK=$latest_sum_check
elif [ $latest_sum_check != $EXISTING_SUM_CHECK ]; then
```

This uses a unary operation to check if the string has zero length.  != requires that both sides of the test have a non-empty value.

Another way to solve this can be:

```
if [ "X${latest_sum_check}" != "X${EXISTING_SUM_CHECK}" ]; then
```

Which forces both values to have a value of at least X if the variable is unset or null or ''.

Also to note, typically if you're comparing two numbers -ne is recommended over !=, as != is reserved for strings.  However -ne only works for numerals [0-9], and not hexidecimal comparisons such as md5sum results.

Comment: Also note the extraneous spaces surrounding their assignment statement `EXISTING_SUM_CHECK = $latest_sum_check`